How would I display a Chromium Embedded Framework instance in an XPlane Window?
I need to display a html page in an X-Plane 12 window. I would like to use Chromium Embedded Framework if possible, as it seems to be the easiest and best maintained of the similar projects out there. I can make a x-plane window, and a CEF window separately, but cannot get the CEF window into X-Plane.
All help would be greatly appreciated
I have tried rendering the CEF window to a texture using a bit of code I found online. I wasn't able to get it to work. I got quite a few compiler errors that I tried to fix, but couldn't.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
